# How can I remove the right click menu from SWF files?

Tags: html, swf, right-click

I have an SWF file and a HTML page - when I open the HTML page it will run my SWF file. When I right click on the SWF file I will see these right click menu items:

```
Settings...
About Adobe Flash Player 10...
```

I want to remove these right click menu items - when I right click on the SWF I should see nothing.

How can I do that?

Comment: Are you a developer or user?

Comment: Hi ChrisF, I'm a Simple User.

Comment: That's fine. It's just that if you were a developer a) this would be the wrong site and b) the answer would be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't. Flash lets the developer *change* the right-click menu, but not eliminate it. You can remove most items, but not the two shown above.

I'm a couple of versions behind on my Flash development environment, but I don't believe this has changed in CS5 or CS5.5.

In some browsers you could drop a transparent object on top of the Flash movie to prevent it from receiving right-click events but I'm not aware of any cross-browser universally-effective way to do that.

Comment: Hi CarlF, I'm using a software which converts html files into exe, it uses IE browser. So How can I drop a transparent object to prevent right click menu in IE? any way?

Answer (score 0):

Please supply some more information...

As an end-user, you can't do it without external tools.
About the external tools - it depends on the browser you use.

As a developer - it depend on your development platform.

Comment: I use IE Browser.